# weight paint is deforming my mesh?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

so im trying to build a face rig and using only the bottom lip bones i assign weight paint and im wondering why its deforming the mesh like that and what a possible solution would be thanks [image]

[image]

Comment: Is the rig in rest pose (same as in edit mode)? Did you Apply (Ctrl A) rot and scale to both mesh and rig?

Comment: yes but that only reset my pose i think it has to do with weight paint...